# How to access and interact with Shadow DOM using Watir?

Tags: jquery, ruby, selenium, watir, shadow-dom

I need to access this page chrome://downloads/ and check that a file has been downloaded but it's Shadow DOM.

I've found this article how to access DOM Elements With Selenium Webdriver.
http://jeremysklarsky.github.io/blog/2015/06/13/accessing-shadow-dom-elements-with-selenium-webdriver/

But this is written in JS

```js
driver.executeScript("return $('body /deep/ <#yourSelector>')")

driver.executeScript("return $('body /deep/ ._mm_column')[0].textContent").then(function(title){
  title.should.contain(segmentName);
});
```

Having changed that to Watir syntax, my code works but doesn't return me the desired results:

```ruby
    execute_script("return $('<#file-link>')")

    execute_script("return $( '<:contains(test-file.mp3)>')")
```

I'm just getting nils in the console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvAqo.png)

But what I'd like to get is to make sure that the element is present.

Comment: Everything given as an argument for execute_script is going to be javascript, as you are asking the browser to execute whatever you provide there..  Won't matter if the language making the call is Ruby or Java or JS  So likely if you are trying to follow the example you will need to include the `body /deep/ ` portion shown in the examples in your code also.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by titusfortner's deleted answer, Selenium Easy had a related article, "[Working with Shadow DOM Elements using Webdriver](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/accessing-shadow-dom-elements-with-webdriver)". It turns out that you can get a shadow element via JavaScript and then interact with it's descendants as normal.

However, due to the way Watir is written, I had to monkey-patch `Watir::Browser` to make it work. I'll see if I can get a more permanent fix, but for now, here's a working example:

```
require 'watir'

# Monkey-patch due to being unable to check the tag name of the shadow root
class Watir::Browser
  def wrap_element(scope, element)
    Watir.element_class_for(element.tag_name.downcase).new(scope, element: element)
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError # need a better rescue
    Watir::Element.new(scope, element: element)
  end
end

def expand_root_element(element, browser)
    browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element)
end

browser = Watir::Browser.new

# Create a download item
browser.goto('https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/chromedriver_win32.zip')
browser.goto('chrome://downloads')

# Navigate the shadow DOM to the download items
download_manager = browser.element(css: 'downloads-manager')
shadow_download_manager = expand_root_element(download_manager, browser)

download_items = shadow_download_manager.elements(css: '#downloads-list downloads-item')
shadow_download_items = download_items.map { |s| expand_root_element(s, browser) }

# Find a specific download item by file name
expected_file = /chromedriver_win32/
download = shadow_download_items.find { |s| s.span(id: 'name').text_content =~ expected_file }

# Do something with the download - eg wait for the download to complete
download.link(id: 'show').wait_until_present
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to let people know that this monkey patch no longer works and I do not know of a good work around.

The initial problem that Justin solved was that a shadow dom attached to an element actually doesn't have a tag name.  Hence his monkey patch.  But with updates, that patch no longer works.  The initial error is a change in JS errors (see bullet #1 below).  The new problem is that shadow dom's are attached to real elements, but the shadowRoot itself is not a real element.  It's like a quasi-element.

- The error is now a `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError`, so your rescue line needs updated for the correct error.
- Even if you fix that, you'll get more errors `javascript error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'` This is the result of an internal API call on the wire protocol.  For example, I traced the error to `selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:81`  The API call returns an internal 500 error with a payload of `"{"value":{"error":"javascript error","message":"javascript error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.\n  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)"`  I do not  know how to get around this.