# Locating the element which is in Shadow DOM using WATIR

Tags: ruby, watir

I followed JustinKo's other answer([How to access and interact with Shadow DOM using Watir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520550/how-to-access-and-interact-with-shadow-dom-using-watir)) but I don't know how to use it for my requirement here.

here is the text field which I would like to locate. This text_field is coming within the shadow dom as shown below.

```
    <div class="vaadin-text-field-container">    
      <label part="label" id="vaadin-text-field-label-0">Username</label>    
      <div part="input-field" id="vaadin-text-field-input-0">    
        <slot name="prefix"></slot>    
        <slot name="input">
          <input part="value" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="vaadin-text-field-label-0 vaadin-text-field-input-0" maxlength="512" autocomplete="off" required="">
        </slot>    
        <div part="clear-button" id="clearButton" role="button" aria-label="Clear" hidden="true"></div>
        <slot name="suffix"></slot>    
      </div>    
      <div part="helper-text" id="vaadin-text-field-helper-0">
        <slot name="helper"></slot>
      </div>    
      <div part="error-message" aria-live="assertive" aria-hidden="true" id="vaadin-text-field-error-0"></div>    
    </div>
<style include="lumo-text-field"></style><style include="lumo-input-field-theme"></style><style include="flow_css_mod_12"></style>
```

Any specific method which would help me locating this element in Shadow DOM in WATIR?

Comment: Which element is the regular element that has the shadow DOM?

Comment: @Justin Ko what I find was, the entire html code I posted come under the shadow-root node. I want to type in the input element <input part="value" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="vaadin-text-field-label-0 vaadin-text-field-input-0" maxlength="512" autocomplete="off" required="">